# Firebase Function onUpdate trigger - SendGrid "Forbidden" Error sending email

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

The code snippet shown below is receiving a "Forbidden" error:

Error: Forbidden
    at axios.then.catch.error (node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:105:29)
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

export const onAuctionUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document('auctions/{id}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    sgMail.setApiKey(
      'SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    );

    const emailMsg = {
      to: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      from: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      subject: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      html: 'Hello <strong>body</strong>'
    };

    return sgMail.send(emailMsg);
  });
```

Although masked in the code snippet, as the "from" email address, I am using the email account I used when registering with SendGrid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid provides 2 options for sending emails, using API and SMTP.

I was using an API Key generated from the SMTP option and should have been using the one from the API option.

Thanks